# Order by 2 columns with case

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, hibernate

I have a query that searches for user in 2 colums firstUser and secondUser and orders them by first and last name:

```
WHERE first_user LIKE :user OR second_user LIKE :user ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN first_user LIKE :user THEN firstUser.firstName END ASC,
        CASE WHEN first_user = :user THEN firstUser.lastName END ASC,
        CASE WHEN second_user = :user THEN secondUser.firstName END ASC,
        CASE WHEN second_user = :user THEN secondUser.lastName END ASC
)
```

But this first orders the cases when user is at first user then it orders the case when user is secondUser. Is ther a way to order the whole data by first name and last name no matter if the user is firstUser or secondUser?

```
    SELECT c FROM Chat as c LEFT JOIN c.firstUserModel as firstUser LEFT JOIN c.secondUserModel as secondUser
    WHERE first_user = :user AND lower(concat(secondUser.firstName, ' ', secondUser.lastName))
LIKE lower(concat(:name, '%')) or second_user = :user AND lower(concat(firstUser.firstName, ' ', firstUser.lastName))
LIKE lower(concat(:name, '%')) ORDER BY 
            CASE WHEN first_user LIKE :user THEN firstUser.firstName END ASC,
            CASE WHEN first_user = :user THEN firstUser.lastName END ASC,
            CASE WHEN second_user = :user THEN secondUser.firstName END ASC,
            CASE WHEN second_user = :user THEN secondUser.lastName END ASC
    )
```

Models:

```
public class Chat {
    private UserModel firstUserModel;
    private UserModel secondUserModel;
}

public class UserModel {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  You have two first names and last names.  It is not clear what you want to order by.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have chat  table with firstUser and secondUser and the user table has firstName and lastName

Comment: @GordonLinoff SELECT c FROM Chat as c LEFT JOIN c.firstUserModel as firstUser LEFT JOIN c.secondUserModel as secondUser

Comment: @ivaylo when search first user then order by first and last name of first user and same for second user. Am Iright?

Comment: @RahulBiswas I updated the whole query if the first user is user and second user is with name then take that chat and order all chats but the user the other user first and last name

Comment: @GordonLinoff I posted the whole query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the expectation is, is this what you're going for?

```
ORDER BY LEAST(firstUser.firstName, secondUser.firstName) ||
         LEAST(firstUser.lastName, secondUser.lastName) ASC
```

Comment: I will try it I updated the question with more info

Comment: @ivaylo Okay, I have a better idea now. Will firstUser.firstName/secondUser.firstName (or last) every be populated at the same time? If so, which should take precedence in the ordering?

Comment: None the user can be eiter in firstUser or secondUser and I want to order them no matter in which of them it is.

Comment: So if I have chat1-first-user: firstName: 'b' chat2-secondUser: firstName: 'a' it should come as chat2-chat1

Comment: @ivaylo Edited with my interpretation. If that's not what you are going for you need to add sample data that covers each scenario you need handled and sample data for the expected result in each case. Natural language and not-working queries are not as effective as MVE (minimum viable example)'s. See here: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Lack of an MVE is almost certainly why your post is being downvoted.

Comment: Thanks, It seems like it's working, I will test it a little more and I will come back to accept

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE first_user LIKE :user OR second_user LIKE :user ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN first_user LIKE :user THEN firstUser.firstName 
        ELSE secondUser.firstName END ASC,
    CASE WHEN first_user LIKE :user THEN firstUser.lastName 
        ELSE secondUser.lastName END ASC
```